# HTML/CSS formating within the description?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, products-management, html

I understand you can use html within the product description, but is it possible to add full **HtML/CSS formating similar to Amazon product description**

(example: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B008UAAE44/ref=famstripe_kt)

Comment: you can use inline csss

Comment: did you get result

Comment: Hey.  I have put the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per as comment, my solution is working.

So. Inline CSS is working for this case.

Answer (score 0):

- Product => Design

There you can change your css file or add another css file with custom layout updates:

http://www.srikanth.me/adding-page-specific-custom-css-magento/

Comment: Thank you, does this override the current page css or is in used in addition?